# How to load the bean XML file from another jar using ClassLoader

Tags: java, jenkins, jar, classloader, urlclassloader

I need to load the bean XML files which is located inside another Jar file using ClassLoader.
Can anyone help me here.

Comment: Why would you need the classloader instead of using Spring to load those?

Comment: The application I am developing is not a spring application, it a Jenkins plugin. I just need to read these bean XML files from another jar and pass it to another api.

Comment: If it isn't spring related then why mark it as Spring? If the plugin is using Spring you can still use Spring to load it. Else just use the regular way of loading things (it will load from the classpath and the jar is part of the classpath).

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to read files in other jars. These ways are suitable to application in jar mode.  Please see below sample. I just read thymeleaf.properties in thymeleaf.jar file.

1. using jdk ClassLoader
2. using spring PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver

```java
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class MyService  {

    public static void printInfo() throws Exception {
        InputStream fis = MyService.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf.properties");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
        String s = "";
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        br.close();

        PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver patternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
        Resource[] resources = patternResolver.getResources("org/thymeleaf/thymeleaf.properties");
        if (resources != null && resources.length > 0) {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resources[0].getInputStream()));
            s = "";
            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            br.close();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        printInfo();
    }
}
```